# Passing both the event and an argument to a handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React I have created a button, like this:

```
<Link size="button" onClick={this._handleShareClick.bind(this, this.props.shareID)} href={this.props.URL}>{shareText}</Link>
```

What I want to do is pass the share ID, but also have access to the regular event object, to allow me to use `e.preventDefault();`

When I pass to the handler:

```
_handleShareClick = (e, shareID) => {
    console.log(shareID);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The shareID doesn't console log, and I also get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Is there a reason I can't access both of these things, or is there another approach that I am missing?

Comment: You are binding the first parameter to `this.props.shareID`, so you probably want `_handleShareClick = (shareID, e) => ...`.

Comment: Why don't you access `this.props.shareID` directly in `_handleShareClick`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
onClick={(e) => (e.preventDefault(), this._handleShareClick(this.props.shareID))
```

Answer (score 0):

If u need to pass custom parameters, then u can simply pass the parameters to the bind call. The SyntheticEvent will be passed as the second parameter to the handler.

```
handleClick(param, e) {
  console.log('Parameter', param);
  console.log('Event', e);
}

render() {
  <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'Parameter')}></button>
}
```